# Нет порта USB 2.0 Serial

Tags: esp8266

При подключении esp8266 возникла проблема - компьютер просто не видит его. При чём во вкладке "Другие устройства" не отображается USB 2.0 Serial. Что нужно сделать, чтобы компьютер увидел устройство?

Comment: драйвер установлен?

Comment: @Эникейщик, не могу знать, так как в диспетчере устройсвт нет USB 2.0 Serial. Но он должен появляться при подключении платы с жёлтым воскл знаком, что вот я тут, но установи драйвер, однако у меня комп просто не видит даже того, что что-то вошло в порт. Дело не в кабеле и не в порте

Comment: У вас слетел/не был установлен драйвер, нужно снова установить, по крайней мере мне так удавалось решить такую проблему.